# Getting empty array back when processing JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am having data from a json file and would like to push the data to an array. My purpose is to save the data to the database afterwards.

However, when processing the JSON I only get back:

```
admin:~/workspace/src (master) $ node exampleJSON.js 
[]
```

Find below my minimum viable example:

```
const data = {
  currency: [{},
    {
      Name: 'Euro',
      Url: '/currencies/Euro/',
      Symbol: 'EUR',
      Price: '$76.3'
    },
    {
      Name: 'Dollar',
      Url: '/currencies/dollar/',
      Symbol: 'DOL',
      Price: '$27.61'
    },
    {
      Name: 'Yen',
      Url: '/currencies/yen/',
      Symbol: 'Yen',
      Price: '$638234.60'
    }
  ]
}


const coins = []
data.currency.forEach((cur) => {
  if (cur.CoinName) {
    coins.push({
      coinname: cur.Name,
      symbol: cur.Symbol,
      price: cur.Price,
      createdAt: new Date(),
      updatedAt: new Date(),
    })
  }
})

console.log(coins)
```

Any suggestions why there is no data in the `coins` array?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: There is no `coinName` in any of the object. So, `if (cur.CoinName) {` will always evaluate to `false`. I guess you want `if (cur.Name) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you have used cur.CoinName to fetch the values.There is no CoinName used anywhere in the JSON file. Instead you can use just 'cur' just like in the below code.

```
const coins = []
data.currency.forEach((cur) => {
if (cur.Name) {
coins.push({
  coinname: cur.Name,
  symbol: cur.Symbol,
  price: cur.Price,
  createdAt: new Date(),
  updatedAt: new Date(),
})
```

}
})

Answer (score 1):

```
const data = {
        currency: [{}, {
            Name: 'Euro',
            Url: '/currencies/Euro/',
            Symbol: 'EUR',
            Price: '$76.3'
        }, {
            Name: 'Dollar',
            Url: '/currencies/dollar/',
            Symbol: 'DOL',
            Price: '$27.61'
        }, {
            Name: 'Yen',
            Url: '/currencies/yen/',
            Symbol: 'Yen',
            Price: '$638234.60'
        }]
    }


    const coins = []
    data.currency.forEach((cur) => {
        if (cur.Name) {
            coins.push({
                coinname: cur.Name,
                symbol: cur.Symbol,
                price: cur.Price,
                createdAt: new Date(),
                updatedAt: new Date(),
            })
        }
    })

    console.log(coins)
```

> Replace cur.CoinName in if condition with cur.Name, as cur.CoinName is
>   not any key.

Answer (score 1):

In your if condition `if (cur.CoinName)` you just missed property name `cur.CoinName` it should be `cur.Name`